# Problema con aritmética de punteros en C

Tags: c++, c, punteros

Tengo el siguiente código, pero no consigo entender como el resultado de d finalmente es -4.

Se que **tiene que ver algo con la aritmética de punteros**, pero no lo termino de ver claro.

```
double dades[5];
double* pDouble = 0;
int* pInt1 = 0;
int* pInt2 = 0;

pDouble = &dades[2];
pInt1 = (int*)(&dades[4]);
pDouble--;
pInt1--;
pInt2= (int*)(pDouble);
pInt2++;

int d = pInt2-pInt1;
```

El resultado final, ¿ es un `ptrdiff_t` de esos ?

Alguien podría explicarme paso a paso que pasa en cada linea.
Gracias

Comment: ¿qué es -4? ¿`pInt1`? ¿`pInt2`? ¿`pDouble`? ¿`d`?. Date cuenta que no inicializas `dades`, así que podría contener **virtualmente cualquier valor doublé** en su interior y operar sobre eso puede *virtualmente* resultar en -4.

Comment: Es toda la información que me dan en un ejercicio y se supone que debo descubrir cuanto es d. En la solución es -4 pero no tengo ni idea de como llega a ser eso. @PaperBirdMaster Podrias explicarte un poco mejor, tal vez es lo que pasa, pero no lo veo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu duda tiene que ver con la **aritmética de punteros** en C/C++.

En dichos lenguajes, al incrementar/decrementar un puntero, **no se hace** *byte* a *byte*, sino que **depende del tamaño del tipo al que apunta**.

Con un pequeño ejemplo, lo vemos mejor:

```
char *a = 0;
int *b = 0;
a += 1; // Sumamos 1 a la dirección a la que apuntamos.
b += 1; // Sumamos 1 a la dirección a la que apuntamos.
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior, ¿ `a` y `b` apuntan a la misma dirección **absoluta** ? Pues ... **va a ser que no**.

La **dirección abosoluta** quedaria así:

```
a == 1
b == 4 // En máquinas de 32bits.
```

¿ Porqué ? Porque, como dije antes, el *paso* **no es en bytes**. La unidad mínima es `sizeof( TIPO )`.

Como `a` es `(char *)`, se le suma el tamaño de un `char`, que es 1.

Como `b` es `(int *)`, se le suma el tamaño de un `int`, que, en máquinas de 32 bits, es 4.

Esto se utiliza, **aunque no lo sepamos**, en muchas situaciones. Por ejemplo:

```
int b[10];
int c = b[5];
```

¿ Como es que c **apunta exactamente** a donde tiene que apuntar ? Porque el compilador, internamente, hace algo así:

```
c = &b + ( sizeof( int ) * 5 );
```

El tamaño del tipo **se indica claramente** al declarar el puntero, y lo marca **para toda su vida**.

Aprovecho para presentar en sociedad un *curioso* aliado para *cositas con punteros*: `ptrdiff_t`.

El tipo `ptrdiff_t` es **dependiente de la plataforma**; y tiene varias características.

1. En un tipo con signo.
2. Si restamos 2 punteros, el resultado de esa operación es, precisamente, del tipo `ptrdiff_t`.
3. `ptrdiff_t` indica **el número de unidades de distancia entre 2 punteros**, **teniendo en cuenta el tipo**.
4. Para convertir un `ptrdiff_t` en *bytes*, **hay que multiplicarlo por el tamaño del tipo**.

El punto **2** implica que **no se pueden sumar ni restar 2 punteros de distinto tipo**.

Para los que conozcan algo de C++, es de funcionalidad similar al `difference_type` de los contenedores STL. De hecho, para `std::vector< >`, lo normal es que sea:

```
typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
```

Ya le vamos *cogiendo el tranquillo* a esto. ¡ Si no es tan difícil, hombre !

Ahora ya si. Armados con nuestros nuevos conocimientos, nos atrevemos a *meterle mano* al *problemilla* original de la pregunta. Colocamos al lado de cada operación **la dirección relativa** a `dades` a la que apunta cada puntero en un momento dado:

```
sizeof( double ) == 8;
sizeof( int ) == 4;

double dades[5];     // == 0.
double* pDouble = 0;
int* pInt1 = 0;
int* pInt2 = 0;

pDouble = &dades[2];       // 0 + ( 2 * 8 ) == 16
pInt1 = (int*)(&dades[4]); // 0 + ( 4 * 8 ) == 32
pDouble--;                 // 16 - 8 == 8
pInt1--;                   // 32 - 4 == 28
pInt2= (int*)(pDouble);    // 8
pInt2++;                   // 8 + 4 = 12
```

Al llegar aquí,

```
pInt1 == 28;
pInt2 == 12;

pInt2 - pInt1 == 12 - 28 == -16
```

**Pero ...** recordemos que la distancia **depende del tamaño del tipo**. Si no recuerdo mal, quedamos en que `sizeof( int ) == 4`:

```
-16 / sizeof( int ) == -16 / 4 == -4
```

¡ Toma ya !

Comment: ¿Al hacer una operación aritmetica con punteros se efectúa una división entre el tamaño del tipo _adicionalmente_?

Comment: @NaCl `ptrdiff_t` indica **cuanto tengo que incrementar o decrementar un puntero para convertirlo en otro**. En la respuesta, para que se entienda (que creo que no), digamos que he utilizado direcciones en *bytes*. Veo que no se entiende demasiado bien :-(

Comment: _¡No, no!_ me he referido al final, lo que has puesto en el "**Pero...**", pues yo pude llegar a la conclusión de que era -16, pero no entiendo por qué se divide entre `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @NaCl porque `ptrdiff_t` trabaja relativo al sizeof() del tipo, pero yo, en toda la respuesta, he indicado numero absolutos, como si fueran punteros `char *`.

Answer (score 4):

Para realizar este problema debes entender una cosa: el tipo `int` en c y c++ generalmente tiene 4 bytes y el tipo `double` 8 bytes. Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior cuando sumas 1 a un puntero tipo int este apuntara 4 bytes adelante y cuando sumas 1 a un puntero tipo `double` este avanzara 8 bytes adelante. Lo anterior es análogo para la resta.

Ahora mira a continuación la secuencia:

```
double dades[5]; //C/c++ reservará 5 bloques de memoria, donde cada bloque tiene 8 bytes
double* pDouble = 0; puntero apunta a la dirección relativa cero
int* pInt1 = 0; puntero apunta a la dirección relativa cero
int* pInt2 = 0; puntero apunta a la dirección relativa cero

pDouble = &dades[2];  pDouble apunta al inicio del bloque de 8 bytes de dades[2]
pInt1 = (int*)(&dades[4]); pInt1 punta al inicio del bloque de 8 bytes de dades[4]
pDouble--; pDouble ahora apunta al inicio de dades[1]
pInt1--; como pInt1 es un puntero tipo int, este apuntara ahora 4 bytes abajo de su dirección inicial, esto es a los ultimos 4 bytes del bloque de dades[3]
pInt2= (int*)(pDouble); pInt2 apunta al inicio de del bloque de 8 bytes de dades[1]
pInt2++; pInt2 apunta ahora al inicio de los ultimos 4 bytes del bloque dades[1]
```

Ahora como `pInt2` apunta a los últimos 4 bytes del bloque `dades[1]` y `pInt1`
apunta a los últimos 4 bytes del bloque de `dades[3]`, el resultado es -4.

Puesto que: pInt1 está 4 veces arriba si cuentas en bloques de a 4 bytes: parte alta de `dades[1]=4 bytes`, `dades[2]=2*4 bytes`, y la parte baja de `dades[3]=4 bytes`.

```
int d = pInt2-pInt1=-4;
```